# If $E_i$ is a topological space, does it hold $\mathcal B(E_1\times E_2)=\mathcal B(E_1)\otimes\mathcal B(E_2)$?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $(E_i,\mathcal E_i)$ is a measurable space and $\mathcal G_i\subseteq2^{E_i}$ is a generator of $\mathcal E_i$, then $$\mathcal E_1\otimes\mathcal E_2=\sigma(\mathcal G_1\times\mathcal G_2)\tag1.$$ Assume $(E_i,\tau_i)$ is a topological space and $\mathcal E_i=\mathcal B(E_i,\tau_i)=\sigma(\tau_i)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(E_i,\tau_i)$. Let $\tau$ denote the product topology on $E:=E_1\times E_2$.

> Does it hold $\mathcal B(E,\tau)=\mathcal B(E_1,\tau_1)\otimes\mathcal B(E_2,\tau_2)$?

If I remember correctly, this claim doesn't generally hold, unless $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are Polish (complete and separable). However, does at least one inclusion hold in general? And does it hold $\mathcal B(E,\tilde\tau)=\mathcal B(E_1,\tau_1)\otimes\mathcal B(E_2,\tau_2)$ for some other topology $\tilde\tau$ on $E$?

Comment: This always holds for second countable topological spaces, and the product $\sigma$-algebra (RHS) is always a subset of the LHS (for any topological space), as a product of open sets is an open set. I am not sure about your last question, though.

Comment: @C_M Thank you for your comment. Is the notion of "second countability" the same as being Polish?

Comment: No, secound countable means that the topology has a countable basis. Every second countable space is separable, and the converse is true for metric spaces; completeness is not related (for the purpose of your question) to these concepts.

Comment: @C_M Yes, sorry. Quickly checked this notion on Wikipedia and mistakenly read "completely separable space" as "complete and separable space" ...

Comment: It even holds for countable products of second countable topological spaces.